# Snowflake External table refresh with current date parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I want to refresh my Snowflake External table with current snapdate through ADF pipeline. I've a set variable activity which captures current snapdate and I'm passing this "current snapdate" as an input parameter to the Snowflake query.

```
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE WORKSPACE_TITAN_PROD.EXT_CUSTOMER REFRESH @CURRSNAPDATE
```

But the refresh doesn't works. Please let me know if the SNOW syntax is correct?

[image]

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: What does it mean when you say it doesn't work?! do you get an error ?

Comment: @eshirvana I'm using a script task and written the above snowflake query and when I debug it I can see the current date as o/p but in the query parameter o/p it doesn't capture the date either and the pipeline simply executes so no refresh happened. If I do manually by putting date as '2023-05-14' then it refreshed. Is the write query I'm using???

Comment: What is the actual value of @currsnapdate?

Comment: So you have a relative file path of 2023-05-14 in your external file location?

Comment: @NickW this should be today's date and this date will come from a set variable o/p and will be passed to Snowflake refresh query input psrsmeter

Comment: @RakeshMishra if you want to refresh the whole table you don't need to pass anything  , and if you want to refresh a subset of data , the parameter for `refresh` is a relative path to the data subset not a date (according to snowflake docs)

Answer (score 0):

To refresh Snowflake external table with parameter you need to use the syntax as below.

```sql
--relative path in single quote
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE <name> REFRESH '<relative-path>'
```

**To achieve this use dynamic content of the script activity as below:**

```json
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE WORKSPACE_TITAN_PROD.EXT_CUSTOMER REFRESH ' @{variables('curuntdate')}';
```

[image]

**This will pass query in below format:**
[image]

**Reference:** [ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE command in Snowflake - SQL Syntax and Examples](https://roboquery.com/app/syntax-alter-external-table-command-snowflake)